# Inconsistency in C# language syntax

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, language-design

I'm learning C# and came across few things that made me little uncomfortable about the its syntax.

**Case 1**

```
byte num1 = 10;    // works
int ten = 10;
byte num2 = ten;   // Compile error: Cannot implicitly convert 'int' to byte. An explicit conversion exists.
```

In first statement compiler implicitly casts literal 10 (of type int) to byte, conversely it does not do same in third statement.

**Case 2**

```
int[] numbers1 = { 10, 20, 30 };     // works
int[] numbers2;
numbers2 = { 10, 20, 30 };          // Compiler error: Invalid expression term: {
```

The above shortened array-initializer does not work in every statement.

And there may be many more such inconsistencies...

It seems the error-versions are right because those are as per the defined syntax, and non-error-versions (for similar cases) are language created constructs to just make the language easy to code in.

But still shouldnt it be consistent in every place we use it?

Comment: You don't mean grammar, you mean syntax.

Comment: An array initialiser can only be used when initialising an array, not after the array has been initialised. "Initialised" means "when constructed" in this context. And you are not allowed to separate initialisation and declaration with this syntax.

Comment: @MatthewWatson -- `numbers2` has only been declared, i.e. it's not yet initialized.

Comment: An int can hold a larger range of numbers than a byte. that's why the compiler disallows implicit conversion.

Comment: In case 1, the compiler knows it can safely interpret `10` as a byte (because it is between 0 and 255).  It doesn't know that about the contents of an `int` variable.

Comment: Doesn't really matter what the compiler can and can't do. A language is an agreement, so that devs can communicate.

Comment: In assignments the compiler always tries to unite the types used on both sides. In `byte num1 = 10;` the type of the left part is `byte`, the right side is unspecified, and then it (successfully) forces the right side to `byte`. It can't do so anymore in the third line, because the types on both sides are known to be different and the right side is a wider type (more data/bigger range) than the left side.

Comment: I don't see any inconsistency - an `int` isn't a `byte` but *sometimes* a conversion is possible. That's why the *class*, not the language, provides an explicit operator. As for the second snippet - which initializer are you calling? For which array *or list* type? You are *assigning* the result to an int array, but what collection did you want to create in the first place?

Comment: If coming from JavaScript these can seem like inconsistencies.

Comment: @rory.ap You're right, my comment was a little unclear - hopefully my answer clears this up! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Case 1** is a special case covered explicitly by the *C# Language Specification*.

From ***§6.1.9 Implicit constant expression conversions***:

> An implicit constant expression conversion permits the following
> conversions:
>
> • A constant-expression (§7.19) of type int can be
> converted to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided
> the value of the constant-expression is within the range of the
> destination type.
>
> •  A constant-expression of type long can be
> converted to type ulong, provided the value of the constant-expression
> is not negative.

Because the variable `ten` is not declared as `const` then the above rule does not apply, and no implicit conversion is allowed and you get a compile error.

Note that if you change `ten` to be `const int ten = 10;` then it *will* work because, of course, it is now a constant.

**Case 2** is enabled by a feature of the `new` operator.

From ***§1.8 Arrays***:

> The new operator permits the initial values of the array elements to be specified using an array initializer, which is a list of expressions written between the delimiters { and }.
>
> The following example allocates and initializes an int[] with three elements.
>
> **int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3};**
>
> Note that the length of the array is inferred from the number of expressions between { and }. Local variable and field declarations can be shortened further such that the array type does not have to be restated.
>
> **int[] a = {1, 2, 3};**

Observe how it allows you to omit the `new` keyword, even though it is actually using the `new` operator behind the scenes.

So because this syntactic sugar is provided by the `new` operator, it can only be used when implicitly using `new`.

In your example, you can still partially use this syntax when you separate declaration and initialisation, but you must then explicitly use the `new` keyword:

```
int[] numbers2;
numbers2 = new [] { 10, 20, 30 };
```

Now you could argue that the compiler *could* allow the syntax without `new`, since it knows the type of `numbers2` and could infer that the presence of a `{` and `}` means that it must be an array initialisation. However, that would require a new rule and I imagine that the language designers didn't think that it would be used enough to justify adding it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
$6.1.9 explains case 1 very well.
For case 2, I feel syntactic sugar should also support for second statement.

Comment: @SurajGharat I suspect that the language designers didn't really want to support separating declaration and assignment any more than necessary - adding explicit support for this is encouraging programming practises that should be frowned on!

Answer (score 4):

In case1, you are initializing with a literal. This

```
byte b = 10;
```

is ok because the literal "10" is a valid byte. Assigning a variable to another variable rather than a literal is not the same thing. 
In the next example, imagine if we did this:

```
int ten = 10;
ten = 100000; // evil
byte b = ten;
```

The first case only worked because C# was pretty nice by trying its best to interpret the "10" literal as a byte. It can do that because it has the *value* available at compile time, and it's 0..255. When assigning the value from `ten` it can't know the value is limited to 0..255 so it has to fail or silently truncate. In the case of C#, the behavior is to fail.

In case 2 you are using the "array initializer syntax". It's a bit odd that this is only usable for array *initializers* and not generally as an expression. I'm actually unsure why that is, perhaps because of grammar ambiguity. Contrary to what you might think, the expression `{1, 2, 3}`  is *not* shorthand for `new int[] {1, 2, 3}`, it only works the same when used in an initializer.

If you want to do what you (perhaps) intended in Case 2 you would have to use the full (non-initializer) expression:

```
int[] numbers1 = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };     
int[] numbers2;
numbers2 = new int[] { 20, 30, 40 };
```

Edit: As pointed out in a comment there *is* a shorthand for non-initializer array creation: you can drop the array type like so, and only do `new[] {10, 20, 30}` in cases where the type can be inferred from the values.

Comment: In this particular case, the `int` part of the array creation can be dropped: `new[] { 10, 20, 30 }` will create an `int[]`, since each of the items is an `int`.